# How to call the JSON value using nodejs when the value is having hyphen

Tags: javascript

My JSON value has a value with hyphen like database-name.

I wanted to replace the value of the database-name using below code

```
    result.databases.database-name = 'ArangoDB';
```

But it is showing error, How to call the JSON value when the value is having hyphen

Here is a code

```
const fs = require("fs");
const xml2js = require('xml2js');

fs.readFile("databases.xml", "utf-8", (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }

    xml2js.parseString(data, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }

        result.databases.database-name = 'ArangoDB';

       
        const builder = new xml2js.Builder();
        const xml = builder.buildObject(result);

        fs.writeFile('new-databases.xml', xml, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }

            console.log(`Updated XML is written to a new file.`);
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: When having characters like `-` in your key you have to use `result.databases["database-name"]`

Comment: It is working fine and not showing any error now. But the value is not replaced in the xml file, is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do like this:

`result.databases["database-name"]`

That's the way to access properties when you have a hyphen in their key names.

Comment: It is working fine and not showing any error now.

Comment: But the value is not replaced in the xml file, is there any other way?

Comment: I've done a test locally here and it worked. Are you sure you're changing the correct property at the correct place? Try doing a `console.log(result.databases['database-name']);` before doing the change to `ArangoDB` and check if you're getting the current database name from the file.

Comment: Thanks - the value is correct in console.log. But not getting updated in xml. Let me check my code for saving xml

Answer (score 1):

You can use this syntax to access object members with a `string` as the key

```js
result.databases["database-name"] = 'ArangoDB';
```

Here is the [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)